# Query five tables including two inter-related junction tables to form View

Tags: postgresql, join, view

I have three tables (surveypoint, sample, fldwrk_images): a surveypoint can have many or no samples, and both surveypoint and sample can have many or no images, and both surveypoint and sample are linked to two separate junction tables as an image can be of one or more samples/surveypoints. These two many to many relationships are formed by two junction tables (svypnt_fldwrk_image_junc and sample_fldwrk_image_junc) that connect the table fldwrk_images.

I am trying to create a view that will result in each row containing the surveypoint info, the sample info related to the surveypoint (if there), and the image info (if there). As the images are from junction tables I am expecting duplicate info on surveypoint and sample, and that is fine, but I would want the view to be distinct on image_id.

Below is my attempt at the query that when run goes on forever, so clearly it is flawed, and I can't figure out how to do it.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW query_fldwrk_images_by_surveypoint_and_sample AS 
SELECT DISTINCT ON (fi1.fldwrk_image_id) svypnt_fldwrk_image_junc.svypnt_fldwrk_image_junc_id,
fi1.image_path,
fi1.image_name,
fi1.iptc_caption,
fi1.iptc_keywords,
srpnt1.surveypoint_name,
fi1.fldwrk_image_id,
sam1.sample_name
FROM surveypoint as srpnt1
LEFT JOIN sample sam2 ON srpnt1.surveypoint_id = sam2.surveypoint_id,
svypnt_fldwrk_image_junc
LEFT JOIN fldwrk_image fi1 ON svypnt_fldwrk_image_junc.fldwrk_image_id = fi1.fldwrk_image_id
LEFT JOIN surveypoint srpnt2 ON svypnt_fldwrk_image_junc.surveypoint_id = srpnt2.surveypoint_id,
sample_fldwrk_image_junc
LEFT JOIN fldwrk_image fi2 ON sample_fldwrk_image_junc.fldwrk_image_id = fi2.fldwrk_image_id
LEFT JOIN sample sam1 ON sample_fldwrk_image_junc.sample_id = sam1.sample_id;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### CROSS JOIN

The problem is that this

```
FROM surveypoint as srpnt1
LEFT JOIN sample sam2 ON srpnt1.surveypoint_id = sam2.surveypoint_id
```

does not join in any way to this

```
svypnt_fldwrk_image_junc
LEFT JOIN fldwrk_image fi1 ON svypnt_fldwrk_image_junc.fldwrk_image_id = fi1.fldwrk_image_id
LEFT JOIN surveypoint srpnt2 ON svypnt_fldwrk_image_junc.surveypoint_id = srpnt2.surveypoint_id
```

and neither joins to this

```
sample_fldwrk_image_junc
LEFT JOIN fldwrk_image fi2 ON sample_fldwrk_image_junc.fldwrk_image_id = fi2.fldwrk_image_id
LEFT JOIN sample sam1 ON sample_fldwrk_image_junc.sample_id = sam1.sample_id
```

(Note that the table aliases are different on `surveypoint` and `sample`.) This creates a `CROSS JOIN` resulting in a Cartesian product of the three groups of tables. If each group has 1,000 records, the view will have 1,000,000,000 records, which takes *some* time to prepare.

Change the aliases on `sample` and `surveypoint` and re-arrange the join order would make your view be prepared quickly.

### DISTINCT ON

You note that you want the view to be `DISTINCT ON` the `image_id` associated with the `surveypoint`. There are a few points to consider here:

- Unless you include an `ORDER BY` clause, the record that is retained in the view is indeterminate, even to the point that separate queries against the view can display different results.
- Apparently a `surveypoint` can have many images and an image can be associated with a `surveypoint` and any of its `sample`s. Fine. But can a single image be associated with multiple `surveypoint`s? That does not sound very logical.

Rephrasing your narrative (and adding some guesswork that would seem to make sense given your query in the question), it appears you want this (in pseudo-SQL):

```
CREATE VIEW query_fldwrk_images_by_surveypoint_and_sample AS
  SELECT surveypoint_info, sample_info, image_info
  WHERE image_info IS ANY image_info LINKED TO svy_pnt
  OR ELSE ANY image_info LINKED TO ANY smpl LINKED TO svy_pnt NOT USED IN OTHER RECORDS
```

Because of the many-to-many relationships over two paths and the requirement of `DISTINCT ON` the image_id, **this cannot be done in a simple query in a deterministic way**. The problem, in short, is that you have to create combinations of `surveypoint-sample-image` and keep track of what images you assign where, possibly back-tracing if you encounter a `NULL` somewhere (e.g. you can have a `surveypoint` with no image linked to it, so you use the image of the first available `sample`. If any other sample has only that image linked to it, it'll come up without a valid image (because of the `DISTINCT ON` clause), while there may be "extra" images in other samples).

You should relax your `DISTINCT ON` requirement to make this a relatively simple view. Such a relaxation could be of the form: Give all surveypoints with their samples and the image of the surveypoint; if the image is `NULL`, use any image of the sample point. You may end up with identical images from different samples, but at least you'll have your view.

The only way that I can see that this might work is to reverse the logic: instead of linking images to survey points and samples, link the latter to the image, but you'll have the same problems with the many-to-many conflicts (i.e. which survey point or sample to assign to which image). A recursive CTE would do the hard work, but resolving the conflicts would still be very hard.

Comment: "Change the aliases on sample and surveypoint and re-arrange the join order" - change aliases to what; and change order to what?

Comment: "But can a single image be associated with multiple surveypoints? That does not sound very logical." - The image/surveypoint relation is many to many (and why I needed a junction table) because in the survey, two survey points may be close by and can be seen in one image (important as it shows the context of the surveypoints). Thanks for your psuedo-SQL, but I'm a new user and can't 'convert' that into actual sql to try the query: I'd be grateful if you could tell what "is any" and "linked to" would be in terms of joins.

Comment: The important point is that your requirement to have all images distinct from other images cannot be implemented in standard SQL, to the best of my knowledge. If you relax that requirement (allow duplicates) then the query becomes rather easy.

Comment: "images distinct from other images cannot be implemented in standard SQL" - so, it would seem that the structure of my database is at fault? The disallowing of duplicates is a requirement of the query as I don't want duplicates.

Comment: The structure of your database reflects how you specified your "Universe-of-Discourse", which allowed for a single image to be associated with multiple survey points and/or multiple samples. That decision results in the situation that your current requirement cannot be met with a simple SQL query. See updated answer.

Comment: I've been away pondering my database structure. If I want the query to come out as I want, i.e. with distinct on image_id and info on surveypoint and sample is it possible to restructure the database with a new junction table that would link the images table to both the surveypoint and sample tables, i.e. for a given row the new junction table would have the junction_table_id as pk, a surveypoint_id, a sample_id, and an image_id. For some rows the sample_id would be empty as there are some surveypoints with images with no related samples. Is this kind of junction feasible and good practice?

Answer (score 1):

(I'm answering my own question to elicit replies/comments to my new db structure: I'm not sure of the etiquette of this...)

Based on the first answer provided by Patrick, it appears that as my db was structured I could not query it to extract the info I needed. To resolve this, I restructured the db from having two junction tables linking three tables to one junction table linking the three tables, with the new junction table having a junction_pk, an image_id, a surveypoint_id, and a sample_id. Because some surveypoints have no associated samples, in the new junction table there are some rows with no sample_id data.

In order to extract all the info I need I create a view using select distinct on junction_id on surveypoints first using a sample_id is null then a union on sample_id is not null (this appears to be required as otherwise the data on surveypoints with no associated samples appears empty as there is no way to say that the sample_id relate to each other).

The new structure appears to work and does not produce erroneous connections in my required view (the view is based on another query - query.1 - which queries six tables first to bring together the info needed to associate with the images).

My question is: is this kind of junction table linking three tables good practice in databases: will this cause problems down the line I'm not aware of? Is my way of creating the view by using the union method appropriate/efficient?

The query is:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW query_surv_sam_images_irll14 AS 
     SELECT DISTINCT ON (junc1.svy_sam_image_junc_id) fi1.iptc_caption,
        query1.surveypoint_name,
        query1.sample_name,
        query1.material_name,
        query1.surv_formation_name,
        query1.surv_newcode,
        query1.samp_formation_name,
        query1.samp_newcode,
        query1.surveypoint_type_name,
        query1.surveypoint_descrp_brief,
        query1.surveypoint_description,
        query1.survey_date,
        query1.sample_type_name,
        query1.geochemical,
        query1.outcrop_grp_name,
        query1.outcrop_grp_descrp,
        query1.locality_name,
        query1.area_name,
        query1.waterbasin_name,
        query1.townland_name,
        query1.county,
        query1.country_name,
        junc1.svy_sam_image_junc_id,
        junc1.surveypoint_id,
        query1.surv_id,
        junc1.sample_id,
        query1.samp_id,
        fi1.image_name,
        fi1.image_path,
        fi1.geom
       FROM svy_sam_image_junc junc1
  JOIN fldwrk_image fi1 ON fi1.fldwrk_image_id = junc1.fldwrk_image_id
   LEFT JOIN query_srpnts_samples_irll14 query1 ON query1.surv_id = junc1.surveypoint_id
  WHERE junc1.sample_id IS NULL
UNION
     SELECT DISTINCT ON (junc1.svy_sam_image_junc_id) fi1.iptc_caption,
        query1.surveypoint_name,
        query1.sample_name,
        query1.material_name,
        query1.surv_formation_name,
        query1.surv_newcode,
        query1.samp_formation_name,
        query1.samp_newcode,
        query1.surveypoint_type_name,
        query1.surveypoint_descrp_brief,
        query1.surveypoint_description,
        query1.survey_date,
        query1.sample_type_name,
        query1.geochemical,
        query1.outcrop_grp_name,
        query1.outcrop_grp_descrp,
        query1.locality_name,
        query1.area_name,
        query1.waterbasin_name,
        query1.townland_name,
        query1.county,
        query1.country_name,
        junc1.svy_sam_image_junc_id,
        junc1.surveypoint_id,
        query1.surv_id,
        junc1.sample_id,
        query1.samp_id,
        fi1.image_name,
        fi1.image_path,
        fi1.geom
       FROM svy_sam_image_junc junc1
  JOIN fldwrk_image fi1 ON fi1.fldwrk_image_id = junc1.fldwrk_image_id
   LEFT JOIN query_srpnts_samples_irll14 query1 ON query1.samp_id = junc1.sample_id
  WHERE junc1.sample_id IS NOT NULL
  ORDER BY 2, 3, 1, 28;
```